# add caption to Subfigures

Tags: subfloats

how to add caption to the multiple subfigures whose  code is given as

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centerline{%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{CircleTemplate.eps}%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{CircleOlimpicStarting.eps}%
}%
\centerline{%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth] {CircleOlimpicFinishing.eps}%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth] {CircleOlimpicFinishingWithNoise.eps}%
}%
\caption{Some long long caption}
\label{fig:OlimpicCircleTT1}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [subfig-package](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/subfig/subfig.pdf) and adapt e.g. the first simple example to your code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
\centering
\subfloat[First.]{...}\qquad
\subfloat[Second figure.]{...}\\
\subfloat[Third.]{\label{3figs-c}...}%
\caption{Three sub-floats.}
\label{3figs}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution could be based on `subcaption` package and its `subfigure` environments. Each `subfigure` environment can contain a `\caption` and `\label` statement and can thus be cross-referenced using the `\ref` mechanism.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  % remove "demo" option in your real document
\usepackage{subcaption}      % provides "subfigure" environment
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{CircleTemplate.eps}
\caption{First subfigure caption}\label{fig:a}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill}  % spread out the first and second subfigures 
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{CircleOlimpicStarting.eps}%
\caption{Second subfigure caption}\label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip  % create some vertical separation between the two rows of subfigures

\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth] {CircleOlimpicFinishing.eps}
\caption{Third subfigure caption}\label{fig:c}
\end{subfigure}
\hspace*{\fill} % spread out the third and fourth subfigures 
\begin{subfigure}{0.48\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth] {CircleOlimpicFinishingWithNoise.eps}%
\caption{Fourth subfigure caption}\label{fig:d}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Some long long caption} \label{fig:OlimpicCircleTT1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```